# How to know how much storage was occupied by a Python / Django application?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgis

I developed a web application with Python and Django. I would like to limit the amount of space used for each user, since in the application it is possible to insert images and documents.

I use Postgres as DBMS.

How do I know how much storage a user occupies in Python and Django?

Answer (score 0):

[FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) has a size attribute, so for a user you will need to find all their documents and total up the sizes.